# reassigning row/list in a 2d list in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to create an 2d list in python that was x + 1,y + 1 sized and had some initial values. Those initial values are that the first row contains the numbers 0 to 'x' and the first column contains the numbers 0 to 'y' (both inclusively)

Lets say x and y were 3 and 4.

So I went:
    listName = [range(0, x + 1)] * (y + 1);

This gives me a 2d list that has 5 rows and each row is a list with the numbers 0 to 3 giving 4 indexes on each row (4 columns):

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

I understand that at this point I have a 2d array, but each row is an instance so if I changed any value in each row, all the rows would reflect that change. So to fix that I decided to set each row to a new unique list:

```
for row in listName:
    row = range(0, x + 1);
```

But I noticed that this seems to have no effect, my original list  Even if I went:

```
for row in listName:
    row = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
```

Printing before and after the assignment shows 'row' is getting changed, but outside the loop, I get my original list when I print it. Even though I've found another way to do what I want, I can't seem to figure out why this happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice-assign in order to modify the existing list, instead of just rebinding the name.

```
row[:] = ...
```

Also, you're constructing it incorrectly.

```
listName = [range(0, x + 1) for z in range(y + 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and using slice-assignment does work for assignment, though keeps all the row-lists as instances to each other.

The second line you wrote does indeed work, but I've never really seen creating a list (or any code) in front of a for loop before. By changing the first part, it see that it somehow 'multiples' that list like before ( but making a new unique list each time) per iteration of the loop, but I can't quite grasp how a for loop can do that, nor can I find anything like that in the documentation.

Can you explain what it's really doing?

Comment: The original code creates a list that contains y + 1 copies of a reference to the same list. The new code is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Ah I see. I was mislead by just looking at 'loop'. I shall go read about list comprehensions now.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a list to a name you're effectively instantiating a new list. Python has a special syntax that allows you to do this:

```
row[:] = …

>>> listName = [range(0, x + 1)] * (y + 1);
>>> listName
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> for row in listName:
...     row[:] = range(0, x+1)
... 
>>> listName
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> for row in listName:
...     row[:] = range(0, x+6)
... 
>>> listName
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

But based on your original question, did you want to do this?

```
>>> [range(0, x+1)] + [[i] + [0]*x for i in xrange(1, y+1)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.  Like my other reply, I'm a bit confused how adding a for loop at the end works though.

Comment: @mitim It's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that creates a list of lists. The first value in each list is the incremental value of `y`, and the second - `x`th value are all zeros.

Comment: Yes, another reply mentioned it and I looked it up. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

> But I noticed that this seems to have no effect, my original list

Because `row = range(0, x + 1)` does not mean "The contents of the thing that `row` refers to shall be replaced with the contents of the list `range(0, x + 1)`"; it means "The name `row` shall cease referring to what it currently refers to, and instead refer to the list `range(0, x + 1)`".